# Program to convert given number of days in terms of Weeks and Days

Tags: c++

First I want to the week start with day1 and end with day7, but the problem is when entering day15 the output is weeks: 2, days: 8, but I want the output to be weeks: 3, days: 1, also when entering day22 the output is weeks: 3, days: 8, but I want the output to be weeks: 4, days: 1 and when entering day23 the output is weeks: 3, days: 9, but I want the output to be weeks: 4, days: 2 .

```
int week, day;
cout << "Enter No. of days:";
cin >> day;


week = day / 8;
day = day - week * 7;

cout <<"\nWeeks: "<<week+1<<"\nDays: "<<day << endl;
```

Comment: `week = (day - 1) / 7;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce the expected output with

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int week, day;
    cout << "Enter No. of days:";
    cin >> day;


    week = (day - 1) / 7 + 1;
    day = (day - 1) % 7 + 1;

    cout <<"\nWeeks: "<<week<<"\nDays: "<<day << endl;
}
```